# tvOS Secure Text Field , Text is not Vertically Centered

Tags: swift, uitextfield, tvos

In apple TV application ,  I wanted to make **Password text filed secured** so I checked the `Secure Text Entry`
property in the Attributes inspector , but the **text vertical alignment  of the text became  not in the  center** as in this image [text is not vertically centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhWgu.png) , I tried setting the `contentVerticalalignment = center` but still not working , any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way to fix, but I hacked with `textRect(forBounds:)` in a `UITextField` subclass:

```
    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        guard isSecureTextEntry else {
            return super.placeholderRect(forBounds: bounds)
        }

        return super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        guard isSecureTextEntry else {
            return super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
        }

        return bounds.applying(.init(translationX: 0, y: 10))
    }
```

You might need to tweak the translation to fit you font and sizes.

Note: This isn't necessary on iOS 14.

Comment: worked like charm thank you ,  I had to create a class of type UITextField , inside it I added the above overrides  , then use it for my password text field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is obvious, but I think what’s going on there is that the bullet character used for secure text entry isn’t vertically centered — bullets tend to look better with other text when they’re a bit above the center line. I think it looks fine as is, but one way to fix it would be to roll your own secure text field so that you could use a different character.

Comment: I used different font for the text filed , and that worked also , if that what you mean . thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

@Diogo T's answer  was correct  , however I tried changing the font I am using for the text field and that also solved the problem for me :D